# Can "wherein" be used before "comprising"?

Tags: claim-construction

I am translating a PCT application. Claim 1 recites a device.  Claim 2 depending from claim 1 recites a first device and a second device by defining the device in claim 1 as a first device. Below is my literal translation of claim 2.  Is this   style acceptable?

> 2. The system according to claim 1, wherein the device is defined as a first device, the system further comprising a second device connected to the first device, wherein ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have "wherein" before "comprising". What you wrote looks OK to me. I personally do not like the term "defined", thus I draft that feature "wherein the device is a first device".